# Checking for duplicate username

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing a registration page, for my mobile app, and want to check for duplicate usernames entered by the user/client

I have a button on the page that when clicked, checks availability of the username. However I would like to also incorporate that automatically, if not already done so, when the client clicks submit/go to step 3, 
I want to perform the check for duplicate usernames using Ajax and if there exists a duplicate, then refresh the SAME page with the error message for duplication, else proceed to step 3.

In my HTML file I have some js that does the following:

```
$("#check-username").click(function() {
(...this works as I am able to click the CHECK button
and see if the username exists)
```

I have another js file, that is sourced in my HTML that does the following:

```
submitHandler : function() {
 $("#reg1").hide();
 $("span#step").html("2");
 $("#check-username").click;
 $("#reg3").show();
 scrollTop();
}
```

When I click on Go to next step which is reg3, It does not do the validation for check-username. Is my method/syntax for calling check-username correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#check-username").click;
                           ^^----- Missing Braces
```

supposed to be

```
 $("#check-username").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to go to step 3 only after the validation ajax request returns from the server.  You also are going to need to look at the response from the server to see if it's a duplicate.  For example:

```
$("#check-username").click(function() {
    validateUser();
});

function validateUser(){
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/validate'
    });
}
```

And your submit handler stuff:

```
submitHandler : function() {
     $("#reg1").hide();
     $("span#step").html("2");

     validateUser()
        .done(function(r){
            //for example...
            if(r.isValidUser){
                $("#reg3").show();
                scrollTop();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the instant feedback.